# learn link_to on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, resources

this code:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', home %></td>
<%= link_to 'New Post', new_home_path %>
```

that code above make by default scaffold,
if i add code like this:

```
<%= link_to 'About', about %></td>
```

->:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', home %></td>
   <%= link_to 'About', about %></td>
    <%= link_to 'New Post', new_home_path %>
```

then run/refresh show error,why error? i know that error is add code `<%= link_to 'About', about %></td>` but I see in homesController nothing see home and new_home_path? and in routers.rb same.

Comment: You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39927847/edit) your question to improve its grammar. As is, I cannot understand what you are asking

Comment: i am sorry, Luka kerr4

Comment: Kinoe, try to make your question a little clearer and also show us the exact error message. What do your current `routes.rb` and controller files look like?

Comment: this routes.rb  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :homes
end
 and this error undefined local variable or method `about' for #<#<Class:0x49a2aa0>:0x49a0778>

Comment: `<%= link_to 'About', about_path %>`

Answer (score 0):

To get about page, you need to create route, controller and view page.

`rails g controller static about`

This url will work: 
`<%= link_to 'About', static_about_path %></td>`

if you want just: `about_path` instead of `static_about_path`

then in **config/routes.rb** file

change -> `get 'static/about'` to `get 'about' => 'static#about'`

Comment: For routes i enough understand,# why i must create static controller again with page about if i have home controller, ask,how can about_path to show view page ,impossible each i want make new page i must make with controller.

Comment: @Kinoe if you have home controller already then add about method there `def about; end`, and change route to this `get 'about' => 'home#about'`

Comment: Thx 7urkm3n,I just understand what my problem, i must add home_about + _path.